# Scale image width by defined height proportionally

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hei guys, i'm trying to scale different images with different dimensions (ex: 900:600, 750:400).

**My goal:** Scale an image width if the height is greater than the device height. If i use ipad and change orientation to portrait, my image take a full width but this cause a greater height than the device have.

Is there a way to scale the image with a fixed height and determine the proportinality width?

**What i have tried:**

I was thinking to set the image height and get a new width determined by its height:

```
function ScaleSlider() {
                var ori = window.orientation;
                var screenwidth = (ori==90 || ori==-90) ? screen.height : screen.width;
                var screenheight = (ori==90 || ori==-90) ? screen.width : screen.height;
                var refHeight = slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientHeight;
                var refWidth = slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;

                console.log(screenwidth);
                console.log(screenheight);

                if (screenwidth) {                  
                    if(refHeight > screenheight){
                        refHeight = screenheight;
                        slider.$ScaleHeight(refHeight);
                    }else if(refWidth > screenwidth){
                        var refWidth = screenwidth;
                        slider.$ScaleWidth(screenwidth);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 1);
                }
            }   
            ScaleSlider();

            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "load", ScaleSlider);
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "resize", $Jssor$.$WindowResizeFilter(window, ScaleSlider));
            $Jssor$.$AddEvent(window, "orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
```

**Note**

New version:

```
function ScaleSlider() {            
                var refSize = slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                var refHeight = slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientHeight;
                var deviceHeight = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;

                console.log(deviceHeight);

                if(refHeight > deviceHeight){

                    slider.$ScaleHeight(deviceHeight);

                    console.log(refHeight);

                }else{
                    slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I think you want to keep the slider always in the screen. You'd calculate and determine to scale height or width.

Comment: Yeap, i wanna keep the slider always in the screen, so if i test non different devices, the width scale is applied and images height may be greater than the device height, if so, i'd like to set max height of images and scale images proportionally on WIDTH by given height

Comment: Assuming to scale width to screen width, then calculate the height of the slider it should be, compare the slider height with screen height. If the slider height exceeds screen height, you can determine to scale the height of the slider to screen height.

Comment: Done that already :( nothing changed ... check the note please, am i wrong somewhere? Also i've been trying to change the refHeight value and set the scaleHeight to it... nothing changed

Comment: the refHeight of height of parent container, it is not the device height.